# How to create new command to execute a batch file with Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I need to create a new "shortcut" command in Sublime Text to run a BAT file.

I know how to use build_systems and even build_systems per project.

I want to add the command to the command palette list (in the image), and to bind a hot-key for that.

[image]

How do I do that?

(I'd prefer not using Python for this)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Edit%20Command%20Palette) already?

Comment: Glad having been of help... I'm still considering if making that suggestion as an answer...

Comment: You cannot add asnwer just a link, so add a link, short explain, and example of JSON file. You will get my "accepted answer" :)

Comment: I can't test it by myself in this precise moment, anyway supposing you had no difficulty in installing the package, the JSON should then be the following: `{ "caption": "Launch Batch File", "command": "open_file", "args": { "file": "path_to_your_file/filename.bat" } }` change caption if you wish + file-path and file-name as needed.

Comment: P.S. : are you using Windows? If so, supposing your batch file is named "test.bat" and you have it in "D:\myfolder\test.bat" then use `"file": "/D/myfolder/test.bat"`

Comment: It is not helps, is is just OPEN the file, not execute it. BYW how I add a key binding for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer for this:

## The steps to follow

- Install [edit-command-palette plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Edit%20Command%20Palette) for Sublime Text (it is easy, so I won't describe how);
- Edit the command file: from menu "Preferences" select "Command - User";
- Edit the key bindings file to add hotkeys: menu "Preferences" select "Key Bindings - User".

**The command file (second step):**

```
[
    {
        "caption": "moyshale",
        "command":"exec",
        "args": {"cmd": "c:\\drive\\1file\\cp.bat"}
    }
]
```

**Adding a hot-key (third step):**

```
"keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"],
        "command":"exec",
        "args": {"cmd": "c:\\drive\\1file\\cp.bat"}
```

(It's basically the same, just needs to change `keys` and `caption`)

Answer (score 0):

i'm use build new system like this definition

```
{
    "cmd": ["c:/yourpythonpath/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env":{"PYTHONIOENCODING":"utf8"}
}
```